# Trying to move / drag SKSpriteNode in y axis

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a small game ,and in there there is a pipe , and i want to move that pipe along with the y axis , i want to do thins for finger swipe , i tried to do this with touches began but its doesn't looks smooth , so i tried to use uipangesture , but in not familiar with the sprite  integration ,

can someone help me to achive this

```
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var pipeTextureUp:SKTexture!
var pipeTextureDown:SKTexture!

var pipeUp:SKSpriteNode!
var pipeDown:SKSpriteNode!

var circleTouch: UITouch?

var verticalPipeGap:Double = 60.0


var moveStatus: Bool!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    //set the gravity 
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

   //first create the pipe in a random location
   pipeTextureUp = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PipeUp")
   pipeTextureUp.filteringMode = .Nearest

   pipeTextureDown = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PipeDown")
   pipeTextureDown.filteringMode = .Nearest

   pipeUp = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipeTextureUp)
   pipeUp.setScale(2.0)
   pipeUp.name = "pipeUp"
   pipeUp.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.9, y:  0.0)

   pipeDown = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipeTextureDown)
   pipeDown.setScale(2.0)
   pipeDown.name = "pipeDown"
   pipeDown.position = CGPoint(x: Double(size.width) * 0.9 , y:  Double(pipeDown.size.height) + verticalPipeGap)

   //addChild(pipeDown)
   addChild(pipeUp)


}




func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown" )
        {


            print("touches started")
            moveStatus = true
            circleTouch = touch
        }
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)



    print(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown" )
        {
            //let fingerPoint = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.9, y:  0.3)

               let actionUpMove:SKAction = SKAction.moveToY(positionInScene.y, duration: 1.0)
               pipeUp.runAction(actionUpMove)
                pipeUp.position.y = positionInScene.y

        }
    }

}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown" )
        {
            //let fingerPoint = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.9, y:  0.3)



            circleTouch = nil
        }
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE :**  apparently this is what i had to do  ,

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown" )
        {
            handleTouch(touches.first!, name: name)
        }
     }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown" )
        {
            handleTouch(touches.first!, name: name)
        }
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if (name == "pipeUp" || name == "pipeDown"  )
        {
            handleTouch(touches.first!, name: name)
        }
    }

}

func handleTouch(touch: UITouch , name : String) {

    let location  = touch.locationInNode(self) // get the current point
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location) //get the current node based on the touched location
    let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self) //get the previous location in node 

    let diff = location.y - previousLocation.y; //get the  different of location
    let newPosition = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y + diff);

    var newPipeDownPosition :CGPoint;

    if (name == "pipeDown"  )
    {
        newPipeDownPosition = CGPointMake(self.pipeUp.position.x, self.pipeUp.position.y + diff);

        pipeDown.position.y = newPosition.y
        pipeUp.position.y = newPipeDownPosition.y

    }else{
        newPipeDownPosition = CGPointMake(self.pipeDown.position.x, self.pipeDown.position.y + diff);

        pipeUp.position.y = newPosition.y
        pipeDown.position.y = newPipeDownPosition.y

    }

}
```

now the pipe moves according to top and down direction

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intercept your swiping along Y coordinate you could put this code in  `didMoveToView`:

```
        let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.swipedUp(_:)))
        swipeUp.direction = .Up
        swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeUp.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)


        let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.swipedDown(_:)))
        swipeDown.direction = .Down
        swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeDown.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

Then your methods are:

```
func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("swiped up")
}
func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("swiped down")
}
```

Comment: but how can i move my pipeUp object  in swipedUp funtion , ??

Comment: Depend by your game, if you use Physics it's better to move your object using addImpulse or to correct velocity, otherwise if you have a static object you can use moveTo with a destination point.

Comment: my object os static , but moveTo doesnt give me a smooth transition i already tried with it , imagine its a pipe , and i move the pipe in y axis horizantly can i use  addImpulse easily for this ?

Comment: You can set timingMode in your moveTo action to give an "elastic" movement. Depend always by what you want to achieve: usually I have frequently seen pipes in game that are moved by touchBegan and touchEnd (forced to move only to Y in your case, following the touchesMoved locations).

Comment: Pan gesture is what you want,  not swipe

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can u share a sample code that i can do this